# With each successive call to this `timerMethod` , timerInt's value increases faster than before

Tags: java, android, timer, timertask

I am working on an app, which gets a sort of restart with an event. On the first run, the timer works perfect (1sec = 1 increment). but, on next run (1sec = 2 increment) on third run (1sec = 4 increment) and so on... 
I think there is something wrong with the new TimerTask object being created. but, dunno how to handle it. any suggestion or alternate ?

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```
Timer t = new Timer();

void timerMethod()
    {
      t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
      public void run() {
                timerInt++;
                //TODO bug in timer in consecutive runs. To confirm, see log
                Log.d("timer", "timer " + timerInt);
                /*  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        timerDisplayPanel.setText( timerInt + " Sec");
                    }
                });*/
            }
        }, 1000, 1000);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're calling `timerMethod()` multiple times.

When you've called it three times, you've got three timer tasks scheduled - so they'll all fire each second, and all increment `timerInt`. You either need to not call it multiple times, or cancel the existing timer tasks before adding more.

If that's *not* the case, please provide a short but complete program to show what's happening. The context is fairly vague at the moment.

Comment: Yes, this method is being called multiple times.

Comment: @jeet.chanchawat: Okay, so there we go. Do you really want or need to call it multiple times? Note that I would expect the third run to be 1 second = 3 increment, not 4.

Comment: ok, may be 3... log cat is moving up too fast to see the actual time difference.

Answer (score 0):

The snippet you provided is working properly

- 1 sec 1 increment
- 2 sec 2 increment
- 3 sec 3 increment

etc

So probably the problem is somewhere else in your code.